# How to pass in this action creator to useEffect?

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

I have reviewed other SO documentation on replacing `componentDidMount` with `useEffect` and no matter what variation of this:

```
const App = (props) => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const { fetchUser } = props;
 useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchUser());
 }, []);
```

I keep getting `fetchUser` is not a function.

This is my `fetchUser`:

```
const fetchUser = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios
      .get("/api/current_user")
      .then((res) => dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res }));
  };
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-curran-cxccn?file=/src/index.js

Comment: seemd to be right. maybe add codesandbox :)

Comment: @Omer, I added a link to codesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchUser` action isn't one of the props being passed into `<App />`, so it can't be accessed that way. That function is a Redux action that needs to be imported before dispatch. Try dispatching the action from App.js after importing it from `actions/index`.

```
import { fetchUser } from "../actions/index";

import Header from "./Header";
const Dashboard = () => <h2>Dashboard</h2>;
const Landing = () => <h2>Landing</h2>;

const App = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUser());
  }, [dispatch]);
```